# How to validate TextBox to allow only 1 decimal point - Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, validation, input, textbox, numbers

I want to validate TextBox to allow only 1 decimal point and up to 2 decimal places after it. For number validate only, i am using InputScope="Number", but it can not avoid pasting letters, so i need any validation for paste too (or just disable pasting). For example the user must be able to insert numbers like 23, 23.1, 23.12 and NOT 23.123, 23.1.2 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private void tb1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key >= Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number0 && e.Key <= Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number9 || e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Decimal || e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.GamepadY)
            {
                string strkey = e.Key.ToString().Substring(e.Key.ToString().Length - 1, e.Key.ToString().Length - (e.Key.ToString().Length - 1));

                if (e.Key >= Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number0 && e.Key <= Windows.System.VirtualKey.Number9)
                {

                    TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
                    int cursorPosLeft = tb.SelectionStart;
                    int cursorPosRight = tb.SelectionStart + tb.SelectionLength;
                    string result1 = tb.Text.Substring(0, cursorPosLeft) + strkey + tb.Text.Substring(cursorPosRight);
                    string[] parts = result1.Split('.');
                    if (parts.Length > 1)
                    {
                        if (parts[1].Length > 2 || parts.Length > 2)
                        {
                            e.Handled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (((TextBox)sender).Text.Contains(".") && e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Decimal)
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }

            if (e.Key >= Windows.System.VirtualKey.A && e.Key <= Windows.System.VirtualKey.Z ||
                    e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Space)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```